# Integral of two variable cubic exponential

Tags: integration, airy-functions

I need to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x+a_4y^3+a_5y^2+a_6y+a_7xy}\,dx\,dy$$

If there wasn't the cross term: $xy$ then it would be equal to the product of two Airy functions:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x}\,dx\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a_4y^3+a_5y^2+a_6y}\,dy.$$

but I don't know how to reduce it to that form.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Adrian Keister

Comment: No Problem! I was thinking a rotation might do the trick, but the problem is it's a cubic, not a quadratic. It might still work, though. You could always give it a try. Something like this: https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4003&view=html.

Comment: Under rotation $dxdy$ shouldn't change right?

Comment: Well, lemme think. You'd have $\hat{x}=x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)$ and $\hat{y}=x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)$. That is, if you didn't do scaling (which you could do). Then the differentials transform the same way, because the relationship is linear: $d\hat{x}=\cos(\theta)\, dx-\sin(\theta) \, dy$ and $d\hat{y}=\sin(\theta) \, dx+\cos(\theta) \, dy$. To find out what $dx\,dy$ is in the new situation, you'd have to solve these equations for $dx$ and $dy$, which is straight-forward. I don't think you'd get $d\hat{x} \, d\hat{y}$, though.

Comment: Let's see: a reverse rotation $\theta\mapsto-\theta$ gives the inverse equations, so you'd have $dx=\cos(\theta)\,d\hat{x}+\sin(\theta) \, d\hat{y}$ and $dy=-\sin(\theta)\,d\hat{x}+\cos(\theta) \, d\hat{y}$. The product $dx\,dy=\left(\cos(\theta)\,d\hat{x}+\sin(\theta) \, d\hat{y}\right)\left(-\sin(\theta)\,d\hat{x}+\cos(\theta) \, d\hat{y}\right)\approx(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))\,d\hat{x}\,d\hat{y},$ after letting $(d\hat{x})^2\to 0$ and $(d\hat{y})^2\to 0$.

Comment: I think there's something wrong in my calculations, and I think you're right. A simple rotation shouldn't change an area differential, intuitively.

Comment: Then for $\theta=\pi/4$ it would be zero which doesn't make sense. Under rotation the infinitesimal area shouldn't change I believe.

Comment: Right. Double-checking...

Comment: I'm still getting what I got before. My gut tells me it should be $dx\,dy=d\hat{x}\,d\hat{y}\,(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta))=d\hat{x}\,d\hat{y}$, but that's simply not what I'm getting.

Comment: these integrals cannot converge

Comment: Well, an intuitive argument could be had if we go to polar coordinates via an intermediate step: $(x,y) \to (r,\theta) \to (r,\hat{\theta}) \to (\hat{x},\hat{y})$. The differential areas would go like this: $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta=r\,dr\,d\hat{\theta}=d\hat{x}\,d\hat{y}$.

Comment: @WillJagy The coefficient of the cubic term is square root of one: $i$.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist: Is there other context for this problem that might help us puzzle it out?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Still it would be nice to see why the usual way of calculating the $dxdy$ doesn't work.

Comment: I'm wondering if assuming $(d\hat{x})^2\to 0$ and $(d\hat{y})^2\to 0$ is unwarranted. Not sure how that could correct the problem, though.

Comment: So, does $a_1=a_4=i$? Because, if so, we might get the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma to help us out.

Comment: @AdrianKeister  It is a result of a physics question actually. The coefficients are messy so I preferred not to write but if there wasn't that cross term it would be equivalent to Airy functions with complex argument. I am trying your rotation idea now.

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes $a_1=a_4=i$ but I don't think that I need something so complicated.

Comment: Could you show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a_2x^2+a_3x+a_5y^2+a_6y+a_7xy}\,dx\,dy<\infty?$

Comment: for those no more familiar with this than I am: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Complex_arguments   the path in the original Airy setting goes to infinity in two distinct directions, positive real multiples of the nontrivial cube roots of $-1$ so that convergence is built in

Comment: @AdrianKeister When I rotated the parameters now I have three cross terms which means I cannot eliminate all of them with single parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist: If you could show that the integral I mentioned above is finite, I think you could show via the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma that the whole thing is just zero. Try a rotation just on the integral above.

Comment: @ It shouldn't be zero. It should be some sort of Airy wavelet with complex arguments. I have no idea about it's convergence since it arises from a physically plausible system I am confident that it converges. QED :))

Comment: As @WillJagy noted, the integral cannot converge on the domain given. Just put all $a_i=0$ except $a_0=1$ and $a_5=-1$. Then you can calculate the integral over $y$. The integral over $x$ is $+\infty$

Comment: Actually $a_1=-i$ and $a_4=i$. Does this help?

Comment: And also coefficient of the second order terms $x^2$ and $y^2$ are real and negative.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist: Here's my idea: 1. Show via a rotation that the integral given above is finite. You have to show that the coefficients of the transformed variables to the square power are real and nonnegative - it matters less about the originals. 2. Use the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, perhaps with a change of variable, to show that the integral is zero.

Comment: @Andrei thanks, I put a link about eight comments before this, things are not what they seem; wikipedia shows one viewpoint on restricting the curve of integration in the complex plane. Anyway, the integral endpoints should probably not be thought of as real infinities. All news to me